Websphere Portal not seeing mail address from OpenLDAP
I have connected our OpenLDAP to WebSphere 9.x. I am able to see the users in the portal. However, none of them have their email address. I can only assume it's because portal uses "Email" where OpenLDAP uses "Mail".
I need to map mail to Email but none of the documents online match the choices I see. I go to Security / Global Security / Federated / Repositories / myLDAP / Additional Properties. That's where things don't match. I see two choices for mapping but the screens don't seem to ask for values that would connect Mail to Email.
